# Getting user input from login page and comparing it to the values in th database

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am having some problems on for my. The idea is to get the users input from the login view and compare it to records in the database.Please how do I do it ?

**This is my LoginController.php code**

```
 function login(){
 $this->loadModel('Login');
 $user = $this->request->data ['Login'] ['Username'];
 $pass = $this->request->data ['Login'] ['Password'];

    $this->Login->find('all', array(
   'conditions' => array('username' => $dbuser,'password' => $dbpass))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  );

 if ($user == $dbuser){

 if($pass == $dbpass){
 $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome, ' . $user);
 $this->redirect(array('action' => 'home'));
 $this ->set('title_for_layout', 'Homepage');   }
 }
 else
  {
   $this->Session->setFlash('Error Login In!');
  }

  }
```

**This is my View.ctp code**

```
 <html>
 <body background="bgimage.jpg">
 <center>
 <strong><h2>LOGIN FORM</h2><strong>

 <?php 
 echo $this->form->create('Login', array('action' => 'login'));
 echo $this->form->input('Username'); ?>  <br>
 <?php echo $this->form->input('Password'); ?> <br>
 <?php echo $this->form->end('Login');
 ?>
 <br><br>
  <?php echo $this->html->link ('Forgot Password?', array('action' =>'forgot')); ?>
 </center>

 <p> <?php echo $this->html->link ('Create Account', array('action' =>'add')); ?>  </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help

Comment: `$dbuser` and `$dbpass` comes from where? And they are correct the password in db should be hashed so you nedd to compare the hashed version of submitted password

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Post variables?

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Passwords, for security reason, shall be sent to php with POST method.
Also, there is function md5 - use it to encrypt your password, and save it as encrypted value to database on server.
When user sent the password use md5, and compare it to the database value.

For login, it better to find good captca (Ensure that you are human, and not kind of robot/software that trying make logins).

Good luck!!!